# How to save empty objectId in a field other than _id in mgo Golang

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I am trying to save a field in the database using a struct. In this, if I initialize this struct and do no pass a valid bson id as MasterTemplateId while performing an update operation, then it gives error.

For my requirement I need `id` as integer and `master_template_id` as bson id because it is used as reference id here.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"

    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2"
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson"
)

type NotificationTemplate struct {
    Id               int           `json:"id,omitempty" bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    Name             string        `json:"name,omitempty" bson:"name,omitempty"`
    Slug             string        `json:"slug,omitempty" bson:"slug,omitempty"`
    Type             string        `json:"type,omitempty" bson:"type,omitempty"`
    MasterTemplateId bson.ObjectId `json:"master_template_id" bson:"master_template_id"`
}

func Update(collectionName string, id int, notificationTemplate NotificationTemplate) error {
    fetchedTemplate := NotificationTemplate{}
    mongoSession := ConnectDb("test1")
    defer mongoSession.Close()

    sessionCopy := mongoSession.Copy()
    defer sessionCopy.Close()

    query := bson.M{"$set": notificationTemplate}
    getCollection := sessionCopy.DB("test1").C(collectionName)
    err := getCollection.Find(bson.M{"_id": id}).One(&fetchedTemplate)
    if err == nil {
        err2 := getCollection.Update(bson.M{"_id": id}, query)
        fmt.Println("err2", err2)
        return err2
    } else {
        err1 := getCollection.Insert(notificationTemplate)
        fmt.Println("err1", err1)
        return err1
    }
}

func ConnectDb(merchantDb string) (mongoSession *mgo.Session) {
    mongoDBDialInfo := &mgo.DialInfo{
        Addrs:    []string{"127.0.0.1:27017"},
        Database: merchantDb,
        Timeout:  60 * time.Second,
    }

    mongoSession, err := mgo.DialWithInfo(mongoDBDialInfo)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("CreateSession: %s\n", err)
        defer mongoSession.Close()
        return mongoSession
    }
    mongoSession.SetMode(mgo.Monotonic, true)
    return mongoSession
}

func main() {
    notificationTemplate := NotificationTemplate{}
    notificationTemplate.Id = 1
    notificationTemplate.Name = "template1"
    notificationTemplate.MasterTemplateId = bson.NewObjectId()
    err := Update("test_collection", notificationTemplate.Id, notificationTemplate)
    fmt.Println(err)
}
```

after performing this, change `notificationTemplate.MasterTemplateId = bson.NewObjectId()` to `notificationTemplate.MasterTemplateId = ""`.

it gives following error:

```
ObjectIDs must be exactly 12 bytes long (got 0)
```

How can I save empty bson id in the database??

Note: I can not use pointer for `MasterTemplateId` field due to project structure.

Comment: You wrote `Update("test", 1, query)`, did you mean `Update("test", 1, notificationTemplate)`? What `query` is we don't know, it's not in your code.

Comment: @icza I have updated the question for this.

Comment: I guess it supposed to be `query := bson.M{"$set": notificationTemplate}` within `func Update`. Could you proofread the code and ensure that the code you posted produces the error you are asking about.

Comment: @AlexBlex yes I have checked the code. I have updated it. this code produces the error that I have mentioned here.

Comment: Obviously the code you presented in question is not what you run. Your `query` document is not a valid update document: `query := bson.M{"$set": notificationTemplate}`, for `$set` you need to provide `field: value` pairs. Please show a [mcve], until then this question is off-topic.

Comment: @icza in `query := bson.M{"$set": notificationTemplate}`, notificationTemplate variable is of NotificationTemplate struct type which will automatically provide key value pair to `$set` through struct's bson tag. So I guess the example is correct.

Comment: @Amandeepkaur And I guess I tried it and it resulted in a different error. If you need help, provide a [mcve].

Comment: @icza I have updated my post for minimal reproducible example. My bad for not providing enough to produce error.